# Does the Hylian Shield break after a Guardian Blast?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I usually try parrying or using Daruk's protection, but I'm wondering **does the Hylian Shield break after a guardian blast?** My parrying skills aren't exactly reliable.

Comment: You can use the [Ancient Shield](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Shield) which automatically reflects Guardian Blasts, just by blocking.

Answer (score 35):

The Hylian shield, assuming it has not taken any damage before, can withstand [27 guardian blasts before breaking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtbdePUBzX8&feature=youtu.be&t=45). It will only break after a single blast if it has taken substantial damage beforehand. This should give you some leeway in case you don't parry.

Comment: It should be noted that even if the Hylian Shield does break, a fully repaired one can be purchased from an NPC in Tarrey Town, if you've completed that quest line.  The shield can be purchased each time it breaks, so you don't need to worry about losing your one-of-a-kind item forever.

Comment: @Doc, any idea if the purchased shield can have buffs, or is it always a "standard" model?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Just like the original Hylian Shield you find, it cannot have any buffs, it'll always be "standard".  That said, the Hylian Shield is the best shield in the game, even in comparison to all other shields with any buffs they could have.  It has a durability rating of 800 and defense of 90.

Comment: @JPhi1618 just additional clarity: There are several "Unique" items that cannot have buffs, but are repairable/repurchasable/rechargeable.  These include the Master Sword, Hylian Shield, Great Eagle Bow, Lightscale Trident, Scimitar of the Seven, and Boulder Breaker.  The latter 4 are "Champion Weapons", and can be repaired or repurchased at their corresponding champions home city.  The Hylian shield can be repurchased in Tarrey Town, and the Master Sword automatically regenerates over time after breaking.

Comment: @Doc, ok, but there are several videos/screenshots/reports of the Hylian Shield having a buff if picked up after you max out the enemy levels.  After looking a bit more, the consensus seems to be that the purchased one never has a buff.

Comment: @JPhi1618 you are correct. Purchased or rebuilt gear never have buffs.

Answer (score -2):

The Hylian Shield has the highest durability of any shield in the game; however, it will still eventually break.

Once you complete the Tarrey Town quest, Grante can sell you a new one for 3000 rupees.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "does the Hylian Shield break after a guardian blast?"

Comment: @MBorg yeah it does: "however, it will still eventually break"

Comment: @user64742: That says that the Hylian Shield will break after taking enough damage; it does not say whether one Guardian shot is enough.

Comment: If you look at the edit history, the question title was just "Hylian shield strength" when I answered the question. It was then later clarified by edits made by the community. While my answer technically answers the original question, MBorg's answer provides more details and goes into much better detail.

Comment: I did look at the edit history, and the question body has asked "does the Hylian Shield break after a guardian blast?" since version 1. "Hylian Shield Strength" may have been the title, but it was not the question.

Comment: It is confusing when the title doesn't match the question

Answer (score -4):

The Hylian Shield will not break on the FIRST guardian blast but it will break from a guardian blast once it has been hit a lot of times.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This has already been covered in MBorg’s answer

Comment: I just simplified it, thats all.

Comment: @JEREMIAHBERNAL: or, more accurately, repeated it while leaving out useful information.