# What is the Ancient Shield's durability and how effective is it?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I recently heard something about a shield that is called the Ancient Shield. Problem is, I don't know how much durability it has or how effective it is. I know that it is effective against guardians, but is that it? How does it compare against other shields such as the Hylian Shield?

Note: please also consider how hard or easy it is to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [orcz.com](https://orcz.com/Breath_of_the_Wild:_Shields_List), the Ancient Shield has a durability of 32, making it the 4th most durable shield in the game, behind the Hylian Shield (800), the Hero's Shield (90), and the Daybreaker (60).

The Ancient Shield also has a Shield Guard rating of 70, which is the second best rating behind the Hylian Shield (90). This rating affects how much durability the shield will lose when it blocks an attack.

According to the [zelda-archive Fandom](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_Shield), the reason why the Ancient Shield is effective against Guardians, is because it automatically reflects most laser beam attacks while guarding. With any other shield, you will need to pull off a [Perfect Guard](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Perfect_Guard) to reflect beam attacks. It's still recommended to perform a Perfect Guard with an Ancient Shield, however, as this will protect the shield's durability.

Comment: On addition the ancient shield uses one durability per each laser parried.

Answer (score 1):

It is obtained from Robbie at Akkala tech lab. The Ancient Shield costs 1,000 rupees, 1 giant ancient core, 15 ancient springs, and 10 ancient gears.

It is strong enough to block 6 laser beams from guardians, which can be considered one of the strongest enemy attacks in the game.

The Hylian shield, to compare, can withstand 27 guardian blasts before breaking, according to [Does the Hylian Shield break after a Guardian Blast?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364258/does-the-hylian-shield-break-after-a-guardian-blast) but you have to find in the Hyrule Castle in order to use it. Once you've found it and broken it, another one can be purchased in Tarry Town after you've built it completely.

Comment: Does it reflect the laser beams?

Comment: According to other questions and answers on this site, yes. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311511/153954